# Create file if not existing in thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have two threads that should read a file or create it if not already existing. So if the first one already created the file the second should just read it instead of also re-creating it.

```
private void TransformCatalogue(ref XmlReader reader)
{
    var xsltDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xsltDoc.Load("myXsltFile.xsl"));
    XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XsltSettings(false, true);
    var transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
    transformer.Load(xsltDoc, xsltSettings, new XmlUrlResolver());

    var newCatalogue = "transformed.xml";
    if (!File.Exists(newCatalogue))
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(newCatalogue, FileMode.Create))
        transformer.Transform(this.catalogFile, new XsltArgumentList(), stream);
    }

    reader.Close();
    reader = XmlReader.Create(newCatalogue);
}
```

And the calling code:

```
var root = new XmlDocument();
lock (root)
{
    root.Load(reader);
    if (root.DocumentElement.Name == "FC_FeatureCatalogue")
        TransformCatalogue(ref reader);
}
afc = (AC_FeatureCatalogueType)ser.Deserialize(reader);
```

However the two threads seem to access the lock parallely instead of sequentially. Thus when thread one creates the file thread two does same but throws an exception because the file is already in use by the first one.

How can I lock reading and writing the file effectivly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by creating a static lock-object within my class:

```
class MyClass
{    
    static _lockObject = new Object();

    void MyMethod()
    {
        var root = new XmlDocument();
        lock (_lockObject )
        {
            root.Load(reader);
            if (root.DocumentElement.Name == "FC_FeatureCatalogue")
                TransformCatalogue(ref reader);
        }
        afc = (AC_FeatureCatalogueType)ser.Deserialize(reader);           
    }
}
```